# Generating a token for ArcGIS REST Services in VBA

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rest

I am trying to generate a token in Excel VBA to add data to a table on our server.

I am using the following code to generate my token:

```vb
Dim tokenHTTP As Object
Set tokenHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Dim tokenJSON As String
tokenJSON = "[{""f"" : ""json"", ""username"" : ""username"", ""password"" : ""password"", ""client"" : ""requestip"", ""expiration"" : 1}]"
Dim tokenURL As String
tokenURL = "https://myserver/arcgis/tokens/generateToken"    
tokenHTTP.Open "POST", tokenURL, False    
tokenHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
tokenHTTP.send (tokenJSON)
```

The response is a link to the token usage page.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what your question is? For example, which part of the above code is not working?

Comment: @StephenLead I believe my json string is incorrect

Comment: Do you need the double set of quotes? Also, this is a GET not a POST right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own question...

The token login parameters must be formatted as a query string:

```
f=json&username=username&password=password&client=requestip&expiration=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VBA user so I can't help with those aspects. But as noted in your comment, your JSON string looks incorrect so you should start there.

There's no need for the `[]`, the quotes around the entire object, or the double-quotes on the parameters. Try something like this:

```
tokenJSON = {
  "f": "json",
  "username": "username", 
  "password": "password",
  "client": "requestip",
  "expiration": 1
}
```

(I've put it on separate lines to make it more readable, but the line breaks are not required.)

A tip is to use the site http://json.parser.online.fr/ to validate your JSON - this indicates that the above code is valid:

[image]

And as noted in the other comment you may need to check whether this is a GET or a POST.